# return statement returning empty data in console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, promise, callback

I am new to web development and I am trying to create a web app using Node/Vue. Let me explain my code:

**Backend**

```
app.post('/check', [
        UsersController.check
    ]);
```

This is the route that is hit when /check is sent

```
//Check Weather
exports.check = (req, res) => {
    res.send(UserModel.check(req.body.city))
};
```

This is the controller

```
exports.check = (city) => {
    console.log(city);
    city = city.toLowerCase();
    let temp = functions.getData(city, value => {
        //console.log(value) works perfectly
        return(value);
    });
};
```

This is what is called from the controller.

**Frontend**

```
getWeather(data) {
    return http.post("/check", data);
  }
```

This sends a post request to the backend (/check route)

```
async saveInput() {
      var data = {
        city: this.weather.city,
      };
      try {
        const response = await Data.getWeather(data);
        this.weather = response.data;
        this.submitted = true;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },
```

Now let me explain my situation. I want to be able to store response.data into this.weather. However, when I leave return(value) in exports.check, data is response.data is empty on the frontend. However, whenever I put console.log(value), it outputs the correct value (17.04 for example). What can I do to ensure that response.data is able to have the correct value of 17.04?

Thanks

**EDIT**

functions.getData()

```
 function getData(city) {
      const request = require("request"); 
      require('dotenv').config();
      let apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
      let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(url, function (err, response, body) {
          if(err){
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(JSON.parse(body).main.temp);
          }
        });
      })
    }
```

Comment: What does `functions.getData` look like?

Comment: you are not returning the value from backend. it is stored in `temp` variable. you need `return temp`

Comment: @IgorMoraru I tried that and it did not work either

Comment: @Dan check update

Comment: You're passing 2 arguments to `getData` which only takes 1.  Was it supposed to be:  `functions.getData(city).then(value => {`